# SLI enabled, I suspect still one GPU is used. What should be the solution?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

So I have 2 NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M inside my notebook. I got SLI enabled in the NVIDIA Control Panel, however I suspect, from the external heat of my machine, that only one of them is used. I downloaded HWMonitor, to be sure of this. It seems that I was right, is it broken or I just missed something out of my sight?

Comment: Can you provide us with the model of the notebook?

Comment: Sure! It's a Lenovo Y500 model, if this helps.

Comment: You are positive it had dual graphic cards?  Just because your laptop is cool doesn't mean hardware isn't being used.  You can post a dxdiag log?

Answer (score 0):

In Nvidia's drivers there is an SLI visual indicator (or at least there used to be).

Also, another option is to try some of the GPU vendor tools, like precisionx.